# How to check for multiple values in array?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, strpos

I am trying to check for values in array and if value found increment it. I've tried to do it as shown in code below, but not successful.

```
$productdas=array("DAS","DayEnd","DAAS");
if (strpos(serialize($row['pirority']),"P1")!==false &&
   strpos(serialize($row['product']),'$productdas')!==false) 
       { 
         $dasp1++; 
       }
```

I'll be grateful for any help.

Regards.

Comment: What does `$row['pirority']` contain and what is the expected result?

Comment: Why are you using `serialize()`?

Comment: '$productdas' does not parse the variable. Lose the 's

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write an `strpos()` variant that accepts an array as `$needle`; for example:

```
function strpos_array($haystack, array $needles)
{
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle)) !== false) {
            return $pos;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (strpos_array(serialize($row['product']), $productdas)!==false) { ... }
```

*It's also possible to implement this using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match).*

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to search the given string for *any* of the values in `$productas` array and find the number of total occurrences. This can be done with [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/substr_count):

```
$productdas = array("DAS","DayEnd","DAAS");
$count = 0;

foreach ($productdas as $needle) {
    $count += substr_count($row['pirority'], $needle);
}

echo $count;
```

If `$row['pirority']` is `DASfooDayEndDAAShelloDAS`, then the count would be `4`.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/136769)